# How to get date from year and semeter format ('YYYY-SX') using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, period

I have a pandas column called time and it contains the year and semester. For instance in format ('YYYYSX') 2018S1. I want to convert the time format in YYYYSX into date

Input

```
   time
1  2019S2
2  2019S2
3  2020S1
```

output

```
   time
1  2019-09-30
2  2019-10-31
3  2020-01-31
```

Comment: It's doesn't look standard. Why the two first lines give different date?

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(time):
    year = time[:4]
    semester = time[4:]
    conversions = {'S1': '-01-31' , 'S2': '-06-03', 'S3': '-09-30'}
    return pd.to_datetime(year + conversions[semester])

df['time'] = df.time.apply(convert)
```

returns :

```
    time
0   2019-06-03
1   2019-06-03
2   2020-01-31
```

I think there were some inconsistencies in your expected output, but you just need to put whatever semesters/dates you want in the `conversions` dictionary.